# Why is three weeks of increasing jobless claims significant?

Tags: labor-economics

I see stories like this one on occasion in my news feed.

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-10-27/jobless-claims-in-u-s-decline-for-first-time-in-three-weeks

Mainstream news outlets never seem to cite sources, but I think this is the data the link article is in reference to:

https://www.dol.gov/ui/data.pdf

The chart is at a different scale but the overall trends have been down for the last year, and seems that rolling-average volatility has decreased in the last few months too.

The reports appear to be made weekly and we have to known deltas for two of the weeks, one positive 1 000 and another negative 3 000.  Guessing from the range on the chart that is about 10% range of change over the year, which might be of note but compared to the 150+ million people that are of working age in the US, that seems awfully small.

Additionally, we are have only four data points, which would seem ridiculous to make any conclusions based upon.  Also from a layman's perspective, the labour market seems very volatile and with only two directions the market can go, up or down, three times in a row seems like fair odds and would likely happen one if not a few times a year.

From an economics perspective is significant at all or just garbage news?